# solder wire makes solid & glassy residue

Tags: soldering, flux, cleaning

I know using flux makes some residue which makes unwanted contacts between components pins. I dont have any washing liquid or spray to remove it so i simply decided to not use them.

But [my solder wire](https://www.parts-express.com/electronic-solder-60-40-12mm-(0050)-diameter-1-lb-spool--370-034) has a solid flux layer. while soldering with it, some melted flux splashes around, makes some white smoke too.

After soldering is done, two separated material remains on board

First a glassy solid residue which will break under pressure like sugar!

Second some greasy appearance around soldered areas.

[image]

Unlike **lotfett soldering grease** its residue is not conductive. However i don't know much about it just tested myself.

I need to know about this material. Shall i remove it? Is there any way to remove it from the board?.

I created this question to be some kind of reference for the mentioned product.

Comment: A search for that grease yields: *Not suitable for electrical engineering and electronics. (Contains zinc chloride, irritant)*. Don't ever use it. Wash your board thoroughly with water, alcohol. Then let it dry well before powering. I'd guess that the crystalline residue is safe to leave on the board.

Comment: @glen_geek i did not use any soldering grease any more .just use solder wire with some unknown material. Producers calls it flux.

Comment: Flux is a chemical substance that eats away the oxidation layer that metals form when in contact with air. Without it, it'd be much harder to actually solder things together, because that non-metallic oxide would be in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are solders with no-clean flux that you can leave on, but the solder you linked to looks like it has the conventional kind of flux core which should be cleaned off.

You can use a spray can of flux cleaner and a small brush (a toothbrush works great) or you can just use some 90%+ isopropyl alcohol in place of the spray can.

The flux isn't conductive, but can cause long-term problems if left on.  The glassy residue is just excess flux, and the "greasy" substance is likely burned flux and condensed water vapor.

Comment: Thanks alot. With second option(isopropyl) how many seconds i should left the circuit in alcohol? As you may saw the picture, The circuit is messy (chock-a-block) i can't use brush for unacessable parts

Comment: It's hard to give an exact number of seconds.  You can try it and inspect for residue after.  The spray may be worth getting as it's usually pretty high pressure and can remove flux from areas that are hard to brush.  If you have a Fry's Electronics nearby they sell it.

Comment: Sorry for delay, finally i bought a washing liquid plus a general purpose sprayer which makes an acceptable pressure.